# Game FPS for smooth animation

Tags: animation, performance, level-of-detail

I'm designing a 3D game. I have a question about object animation. My question is in case i ensure the 6o FPS game run (on some today's average machine) the distance object is being moved (for e.g. in screen pixels) doesn't matter just because the games frames runs 60/sec? Or maybe if the distance will be to big the animation seem be skippy/not fluent despite that 60FPS?

Comment: I don't understand the question. What leads you to the assumption that an animation might appear "skippy / not fluent" just because it is further away?

Comment: I think OP is asking whether a very fast movement over a large distance will look wrong at 60 fps because the game doesn't get a chance to render enough in-between frames, so the object seems to blink from the start to the finish or flicker in between, rather than move smoothly. Is that accurate, @darro911? Depending on your visual target, this can be addressed with things like motion blur effects or smear frames built into your animation.